# To use or not to use a nested class when dealing with configuration settings

Tags: c#

My program has a ReportConfiguration class that is used to store configuration information for the report.  Logically, there are many areas that need to be configured, namely in how certain types of sections are displayed etc.  A friend suggested that I take these sections and make them nested classes, such that:

```
public abstract class ReportConfiguration{
    private class AssessmentTypeConfiguration{
    }
} 

public class MyConfiguration : ReportConfigration{}
```

Essentially, while I am going to be using these, I will be exposing these configuration classes to other developers who may want to extend some functionality, or write some tools that require the configuration to be modified.  So I want them to be able to extend the configuration class, but there may be certain configuration options I do not want them to touch, or that just logically seem as if they should be nested.

The question: Is it even necessary to use separate classes, or just make one very large class with lots of properties for every configuration option?

Comment: Are you reffering to application.config configuration? I just don't see the base type of *AssessmentTypeConfiguration*

Comment: No, this is a custom class.  My report has different types of assessments

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing separate classes rather than one giant class for a few reasons:

- It helps to group like information together so that it's easier to reason about
- If you want to serialize and/or read the information they contain from a configuration file (or files), it'll be easier and probably more flexible to do so with smaller classes
- If you're going with non-static classes (or ever want to), and are going to pass instances around, it makes more sense to pass limited information around rather than a giant object with everything under the sun

You say there are clearly separated configuration areas, so you should have clearly separated classes to match that. Otherwise, your single class might know too much, and [classes should only be responsible for one thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).